# Best way to report Xcode faults?

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a problem after upgrading to Xcode 6.2.
After exhaustive trial and error, posting on here and on apple dev centre, I got nowhere.

I therefore re-installed 6.1 and all was sunny again in my life.
However when I emailed apple I was told that there was "no special department for technical support" and to go on the forum!

How do I report bugs in their own software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To report bugs: [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com), it is the only way.

Even in the Apple forums you will be told you have to use the bug reporter.

Do report the bug, that is the only way to get the bug into the system.